# Remove old ATA password after swapping SSD to new computer

Tags: ssd, bios, ata

I have a Samsung 850 Pro SSD, that was previously in an old(ish) laptop that only supported legacy bios (not UEFI).

I had enabled the ATA password on the drive to activate the self-encryption.

I've just tried to install the drive into a newer desktop computer, (giving the laptop away to a nephew), but forgot to remove the ATA password first.

Now the issue is that in the new computer, it doesn't prompt for the password, but I also cannot install windows to the drive. The drive is obviously locked.

So my question is, how do I now remove the ATA password. I know the password obviously, but just can't seem to find any option in this new bios to be able to remove it, or enter the password to unlock the drive.

I very much would prefer not to have to re-install the drive in the old laptop to do it, as it's a pain to pull both computers apart.

Comment: run a live linux, and try the hdparm command (something like `hdparm --security-unlock yourpassword /dev/sdb` ). The actual disk name (could also be /dev/sda or an other name) has to be found. Usually `hdparm -i /dev/sda` then sdb then... will tell the model. then use other options to unset this password (--security-disable ...). Don't use the wrong option, there's even one to erase the disk

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up installing it back in the laptop temporarily and unlocking it that way.